# associate tabcontrol tab with string

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, associated-object

I have an application that uses a TabControl to hold a RichTextBox.  The user has the ability to open more tabs as they wish.

I need a way to associate each tab with a string, so that I can store the filepaths for saving.

To clarify, When opening a file in a new tab, I need to be able to store the string with the tab.  In *Java,* I would use a `HashMap<Tab, String>` to solve this problem.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this winforms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<Tab, String>`. More information can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the string to the Tag property of each tab. You'll need to cast from object when using it, but that's the easiest/most efficient way. This property is available on all controls (both windows forms and WPF I believe) for associating objects in the exactly the way you want

As lll suggests, you can also use a Dictionary, which is C#'s equivalent of a hash map.